# Finding $f$ for differential form $w$ such that $Df = w$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to find a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for the differential form $$w = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$ such that $Df=w$.

(1) How can I do that?

(2) I checked if $w$ is closed, what seems to be true. Can we conclude from this that $w$ is exact? (I know that exact always implies closed, but what about the other direction)?

Comment: The $1$-form $w$ is defined on a domain $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ which is not simply connected. A closed form on a general domain need not be exact. Did you try to compute its line integral along a loop around the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This form turns out to not be exact. You can verify this by integrating a line integral around the origin. In particular the unit circle works well.

If a form does not integrate to zero around a closed loop it is not exact. There is an analogy here with conservative vector fields and forces in physics. Terrence Tao's blog has an interesting expository article on this.

Edit: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $w$ is closed $(dw=0)$, but $w$ is not exact because their domain $\mathbb{R}^2 -(0,0) $ is not simply connected [A closed form is exact if the surface is simply connected ("Poincaré Lemma")]